# Minimal working example of ethereum dapp

Tags: tutorials

There are examples about how to develep dapp based on ethereum. They work.

However, they are not minimal, in the sense that readers need to learned things that may be left without. For example, in the follow URL, a framework like truffle is used. I think that people may develop a dapp without using truffle or other frameworks. Also, the problem on this URL is about wrestling. However, seems to be also unnecessary, maybe other more simpler problems can be solved (For example, could adding two numbers be developed on a dapp?).

https://hackernoon.com/ethereum-development-walkthrough-part-1-smart-contracts-b3979e6e573e

The following example is not "working", as it requires the user understand it before it can be used. It should just work without the learning have to understand what the code means. It is better that all the code should be in a github repo and the instructions for running the code.

https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/13/building-decentralized-apps-with-ethereum-and-javascript/

Does anybody have any minimal working example of ethereum dapp?

I'd like the example be to run the dapp on an test network hosted by ganache to avoid having to purchase ETHs.

Comment: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/13/building-decentralized-apps-with-ethereum-and-javascript/ (which I wrote) is pretty minimal. The code assumes deploying to Ropsten, but not much would change using ganache. Just comment out the check for the Ropsten network ID.

Comment: @smarx Are you able to make it dependent on ganache? Also, is there git repo so that I can directly run the app instead copy and paste from the webpage?

Comment: As I said, just comment out the check for the Ropsten network ID. You'll also need to pick the right environment (your ganache node, probably localhost:8545) in Remix when deploying. No, there isn't a git repo, but there's a download link at the top of the code files.

Comment: https://github.com/bellaj/Ballot-Dapp

Comment: I've used this 3 parts guide (it uses truffle for part 2), and it worked wonderfully for me. https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2 I really liked it and it helped me understand a bunch of stuff !

Comment: It looks like on still needs to copy text from the webpage to the unboxed directory. So it is still not "working". Could you please put all the code in github?